# How to extract the protein sequences of a genbank file using R or biopython

Tags: r, python, biopython

sorry for the question, I'm trying to extract the proteins sequences from a genbank file.

```
 gene            complement(516466..532086)
                 /gene="rtxA"
                 /locus_tag="VV1_RS17390"
                 /old_locus_tag="VV2_0479"
 CDS             complement(516466..532086)
                 /gene="rtxA"
                 /locus_tag="VV1_RS17390"
                 /old_locus_tag="VV2_0479"
                 /inference="COORDINATES: similar to AA
                 sequence:RefSeq:WP_011081430.1"
                 /note="Derived by automated computational analysis using
                 gene prediction method: Protein Homology."
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="MARTX multifunctional-autoprocessing
                 repeats-in-toxin holotoxin RtxA"
                 /protein_id="WP_011081430.1"
                 /translation="MGKPFWRSVEYFFTGNYSADDGNNSIVAIGFGGEIHAYGGDDHV
                 TVGSIGATVYTGSGNDTVVGGSAYLRVEDTTGHLSVKGAAGYADINKSGDGNVSFAGA
                 AGGVSIDHLGNHGDVSYGGAAAYNGITRKGLSGNVTFKGAGGYNALWHETNQGNLSFA
                 GAGAGNKLDRTWFNRYQGSRGDVTFDGAGAANSISSRVETGNITFRGAGADNHLVRKG
                 KEGNHTANLANEDISSANGYHSMGKGGYSLSDLHYSVNAVRSTSETVADIDEYTDQTL
                 FKPATDSGESSGDVRFNGAGGGNVIKSNVTRGNVYFNGGGIANVILHSSQFGHTEFNG
                 GGAANVIVKSGEEGDLTFRGAGLANVLVHQSKQGKMDVYAGGAVNVLVRIGDGQYLAH"
```

I'm using a code from a previous answer to extract the protein and the locus_tag, but I want some extra features like:

```
>locus_tag|old_locus_tag|gene|product|complement|protein_id|chromosome|Accession|organism|strain
MGKPFWRSVEYFFTGNYSADDG ..........
```

the result will be like:

```
>VV1_RS17390|VV2_0479|rtxA|MARTX multifunctional-autoprocessing repeats-in-toxin holotoxin RtxA"|516466..532086|WP_011081430.1|Chromosome-II|NC_004459.3|Vibrio vulnificus|CMCP6
MGKPFWRSVEYFFTGNYSADDG ..........
```

this is the code that I'm using, how to add those features, or an other way using R ???

```
from Bio import SeqIO
file_name = 'CMCP6.gb'
# stores all the CDS entries
all_entries = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as GBFile:
    GBcds = SeqIO.InsdcIO.GenBankCdsFeatureIterator(GBFile)

    for cds in GBcds:
        if cds.seq is not None:
            cds.id = cds.name
            cds.description = ''
            all_entries.append(cds)


# write file
SeqIO.write(all_entries, '{}.fasta'.format(file_name[:-3]), 'fasta')
```

But the result from the code only add the locus_tag and the sequence:

```
>VV1_RS17380
MFIKNLSIGKKIAAAFSIIAVINIAFGIFLSTELNTVKSELLNYTEDTLPAMEKVDAVRD
KISYWRRTQFAVFAMNDENQIKQTITRNEGIRREIETELAAYGKSVWPGEEEQTYNRLMS
LWSGYLSTMDKFNDALLAGDKDAAYPILTNSLSTFESIETEVNKLVMILKGAMDSNKNQI
LSSVNGLNTTAVISNIAIFAVMVIMTLLLTRIICGPLNIVVRQANAIARGDLSQDLDRNA
IGNDELGELADATIKMQDDLRQVIDNVIAAVTQLSSAVEEMTQISEMSASGMKDQQMQVT
LVATAMTEMKAAVADVARNTEDSASQAYDANRRTQDGAKETHQMVVSIEEVADIIAKAGD
TVAELEAQSNQINVVVDVIRGIADQTNLLALNAAIEAARAGESGRGFAVVADEVRTLAGR
TQDSTGEITSIIEKLQDLAKQAKHATEDSRTSIGACVEQGNNAQELMGSIEKSIANIADM
GAQIATACGQQDSVAEELSRNIENIHMASQEVAQGSQQTAQACRELTQLSVSLQDVMSRF
KLN
>VV1_RS17385
MNFKKTLLSIAIASASLTPAFSYSAPLLLDNTVHQTSQIAGANAWLEISLGQFKSNIEQF
KSHIAPQTKICAVMKADAYGNGIRGLMPTILEQQIPCVAIASNAEAKLVRESGFEGELIR
VRSASTSEIEQALSLDIEELIGSEQQARELASLAEKYSKTIKVHLALNDGGMGRNGIDMS
TERGPKEAVAIATHPSVAVVGIMTHFPNYNAEDVRTKLKSFNQHAQWLMESAGLKREEIT
LHVANSYTALNVPEAQLDMVRPGGVLYGDLPTNPEYPSIVAFKTRVASLHSLPAGSTVGY
DSTFTTANDAVMANLTVGYSDGYPRKMGNKAQVLINGQRANVVGVASMNTTMVDVSNIKG
VLPGDEVTLFGAQKNQHISVGEMEENAEVIFPELYTIWGTSNPRFYVK
>VV1_RS17390
MGKPFWRSVEYFFTGNYSADDGNNSIVAIGFGGEIHAYGGDDHVTVGSIGATVYTGSGND
TVVGGSAYLRVEDTTGHLSVKGAAGYADINKSGDGNVSFAGAAGGVSIDHLGNHGDVSYG
GAAAYNGITRKGLSGNVTFKGAGGYNALWHETNQGNLSFAGAGAGNKLDRTWFNRYQGSR
GDVTFDGAGAANSISSRVETGNITFRGAGADNHLVRKGKVGDITLQGAGASNRIERTRQA
EDVYAQTRGNIRFEGVGGYNSLYSDVAHGDIHFSGGGAYNTITRKGSGSSFDAQGMEYAK
```

Thanks so much

Comment: cds.description = ''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok tried a little bit, not sure is the most elegant/fastest way of doing it

starting from file from : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_004460.2?report=gbwithparts&log$=seqview        {GenBank(Full)}

here my code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

file_name = 'CMCP6.gb'


# stores all the CDS entries
all_entries = []


gb_record = SeqIO.read(open(file_name,"r"), "genbank")


gb_feature = gb_record.features


accession = gb_record.annotations['accessions'][0]+'.'+str(gb_record.annotations['sequence_version'])

# accession = gb_record.annotations['accessions']
# print(gb_record.annotations['accessions'])

for seq_feature in gb_feature:
    if seq_feature.type=="source":
            organism = str(seq_feature.qualifiers['organism'][0]).rsplit(" ", 1)[0]
            strain = seq_feature.qualifiers['strain'][0]
            chromosome = seq_feature.qualifiers['chromosome'][0]



for seq_feature in gb_feature:
    if seq_feature.type=="CDS":
            if 'translation' in seq_feature.qualifiers:
                if seq_feature.qualifiers['translation'][0] != '':
                    if 'gene' in seq_feature.qualifiers:
                        gene = seq_feature.qualifiers['gene'][0]
                
                    else:
                    
                        gene = 'not defined'
                    
                    if 'product' in seq_feature.qualifiers:
                        product = seq_feature.qualifiers['product'][0]
                    
                    else:

                        product = 'not defined'
                        
                    if 'protein_id' in seq_feature.qualifiers:
                          protein_id = seq_feature.qualifiers['protein_id'][0]
                     
                    else:

                          protein_id = 'not defined'
                         
                         
                    if 'old_locus_tag' in seq_feature.qualifiers:
                          old_locus_tag = seq_feature.qualifiers['old_locus_tag'][0]
                     
                    else:

                          old_locus_tag = 'not defined'
                         
                    if 'locus_tag' in seq_feature.qualifiers:
                          locus_tag = seq_feature.qualifiers['locus_tag'][0]
                     
                    else:

                          locus_tag = 'not defined'
            
                    if seq_feature.location.strand == 1:
                          complement = 'no complement'

                    if seq_feature.location.strand == -1:
                        complement = str(seq_feature.location).strip('[]').split('(-)')[0]
                        
                        
                        
                    pippo = SeqRecord(
                                Seq(seq_feature.qualifiers['translation'][0]),
                                
                                id = seq_feature.qualifiers['locus_tag'][0] ,
                                
                                description = ('|'+str(old_locus_tag)+'|'+str(gene)+'|'+str(product)\
                                                +'|'+str(complement)+'|'+str(protein_id) +'|Chromosome-'+str(chromosome)\
                                                +'|'+str(accession).strip("[]").replace("'", "")+'|'+str(organism)\
                                                    +'|'+str(strain))
                                )
                    all_entries.append(pippo)
                                
# print(all_entries)
# write file
SeqIO.write(all_entries, '{}.fasta'.format(file_name[:-3]), 'fasta')
```

output for your example line is :

```
>VV1_RS17390 |VV2_0479|rtxA|MARTX multifunctional-autoprocessing repeats-in-toxin holotoxin RtxA|516465:532086]|WP_011081430.1|Chromosome-II|NC_004460.2|Vibrio vulnificus|CMCP6
MGKPFWRSVEYFFTGNYSADDGNNSIVAIGFGGEIHAYGGDDHVTVGSIGATVYTGSGND.....
```

I got extra space between locus_tag and | , I dont know how to get rid of it

Its not clear to me what you mean by Accessions, tried two ways (second one is past # in code) and got `NC_004460.2` instead of `NC_004459.3`

Comment: thanks so much it works perfectly, I really appreciate your help !!!!